# Display data in many html's doesn't work using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jhipster

I want to display data in HTML. First HTML disc-log.html looks like:

```
<div>
    <h2>Discs</h2>
    <jhi-alert></jhi-alert>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding-left">
                <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="disc.new" >-->
                    <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>-->
                    <!--<span >-->
                        <!--Create new Disc-->
                    <!--</span>-->
                <!--</button>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="jh-table table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!--<th><span>ID</span></th>-->
                    <th><span>Name</span></th>
                    <th><span>Connection</span></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="disc in vm.discs track by disc.id">
                    <!--<td><a ui-sref="disc-detail({id:disc.id})">{{disc.id}}</a></td>-->
                    <td>{{disc.name}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a ui-sref="connection-detail({id:disc.connection.id})">{{disc.connection.userHost}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <div class="btn-group flex-btn-group-container">
                            <button type="submit"
                                    ui-sref="disc-detail({id:disc.id})"
                                    class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                                <span class="hidden-sm-down"></span>
                            </button>
                            <!--<button type="submit"-->
                                    <!--ui-sref="disc.edit({id:disc.id})"-->
                                    <!--class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">-->
                                <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>-->
                                <!--<span class="hidden-sm-down"></span>-->
                            <!--</button>-->
                            <button type="submit"
                                    ui-sref="disc.delete({id:disc.id})"
                                    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
                                <span class="hidden-sm-down"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

After open this website, all data is displayed. But when I copied the table to another file, then the table is empty. Why? Should I add something in controllers or services?

Disc Log Controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('deviceManagerApp')
        .controller('DiscLogController', DiscLogController);

    DiscLogController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'DiscLog'];

    function DiscLogController ($scope, $state, DiscLog) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.discLogs = [];

        loadAll();

        function loadAll() {
            DiscLog.query(function(result) {
                vm.discLogs = result;
                vm.searchQuery = null;
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Github repository:
https://github.com/Ice94/DeviceManager

Comment: I guess you put `ng-controller` in your template.

Comment: Could you tell me you to resolve this? Is it possible to add some tag and display this data in another HTML file?

Comment: You can use `directive` or `ng-template` for this..

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: please show how include the separate file in your main html file?

Comment: I add GitHub link. I mention about displaying data from discLog.html in disc-detail.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144126/discussion-between-ice-and-hadi).

Answer (score -1):

In controller you are adding result in **discLogs** variable `vm.discLogs = result;` and in html you are using **discs** variable in ng-repeat `<tr ng-repeat="disc in vm.discs track by disc.id">`

That is why it does not display anything. Try to use same variable.

**Note:** `"yourControllerName as vm"` should be in your ng-controller attribute or `controllerAs: 'vm'` in your routes if using router